# Add MSDN Subscription

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn

I bought VS2010 Pro without MSDN..

Does anybody know if I can add the MSDN later?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to be an intriguing question so asked a Microsoft sales representative via their chat live option:

---

This chat can be recorded for quality & training purposes. Welcome to Microsoft. Your estimated wait time is 0 minutes and 1 seconds.
Hello my name is Alisha. How can I help you?

**Cole**: I'm looking at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/buy and there's a version of Professional *with* MSDN and a version *without* ... can the MSDN portion be purchased at a discounted price later?

**Alisha**: Hello Cole.

**Alisha**: Happy to get you started today.

**Alisha**: MSDN licenses cannot be purchased separately from the VS 2010 software or added on later as you are asking.  How many users/developers will need the VS 2010 with MSDN software?

**Cole**: That answers my question exactly. Thanks

Comment: Hehe, were you able to measure the speed of light from that?  Replacing the geo-stationary satellites with undersea cables did screw that up, sadly.

Comment: @HansPassant ~ I think you missed the point where it was a transcript ... I did no time guessing.